# SQL error : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, sql, database, forms

I have some issues with PHP and SQL, PHP is new to me and I have lack of SQL.

I want to add values in tables of my database : values are either taken from a form or taken from another table (as FK).

Here's the database :

```
create database AAA;
use AAA;

create table assure(
id_assure varchar(13) not null,
nom varchar(20),
adresse varchar(50), mdp varchar(60),
primary key(id_assure));

create table vehicule(
id_vehicule varchar(13) not null,
immatriculation varchar(7),
masse int(4),
volume int(4),
id_assure varchar(13) not null,
primary key(id_vehicule),
foreign key(id_assure) references assure(id_assure));

create table reparation(
id_reparation varchar(13) not null,
libelle varchar(100),
couts int(5),
primary key(id_reparation),
id_vehicule varchar(13) not null,
foreign key(id_vehicule) references vehicule(id_vehicule));


create table sinistre(
id_sinistre varchar(13) not null,
libelle varchar(100),
date_sinistre date,
heure_sinistre time,
primary key(id_sinistre),
id_vehicule varchar(13) not null,
foreign key(id_vehicule) references vehicule(id_vehicule));

create table dossier(
id_dossier varchar(13) not null,
primary key(id_dossier),
id_sinistre varchar(13) not null,
foreign key(id_sinistre) references sinistre(id_sinistre));

create table contrat_assurance(
id_assurance varchar(13) not null,
primary key(id_assurance),
id_assure varchar(13)  not null,
id_vehicule varchar(13) not null,
foreign key(id_assure) references assure(id_assure),
foreign key(id_vehicule) references vehicule(id_vehicule));

create table type_garantie(
code_garantie varchar(13) not null,
libelle varchar(100),
franchise int(3) ,
primary key(code_garantie),
id_assurance varchar(13) not null,
id_reparation varchar(13) not null,
foreign key(id_reparation) references reparation(id_reparation),
foreign key(id_assurance) references contrat_assurance(id_assurance));


DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER trigfranchise
 BEFORE INSERT ON type_garantie
 for EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.franchise not between 150 and 600

    THEN
    SET NEW.franchise = NULL ;
    END IF;
END ;//
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER trigfranchise1
 BEFORE UPDATE ON type_garantie
 for EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.franchise not between 150 and 600

    THEN
    SET NEW.franchise = OLD.franchise ;
    END IF;
END ;//
DELIMITER ;
```

My first form sends values to assure table, it works fine.
My second one is meant to send values to vehicule and contrat_assurance table; after checking the form, the browser displays :

> Erreur : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot
>   add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`aaa`.`vehicule`, CONSTRAINT `vehicule_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`id_assure`) REFERENCES `assure` (`id_assure`))

My PHP code is the folowing :

```
try
        {
            $nom=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["nom"]);
            $mdp=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["mdp"]); 
            $imma=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["immatriculation"]); 

            $pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
            $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=AAA', 'root', '',   $pdo_options);

            $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO vehicule (id_vehicule, immatriculation) VALUES(:id_vehicule, :immatriculation)');

            $req->execute(array(
            'id_vehicule' => uniqid(),
            'immatriculation' => $imma
            ));


            $req2 =  $bdd->prepare("INSERT INTO vehicule (id_assure)  SELECT id_assure FROM assure WHERE nom =\"$nom\" AND mdp =\"$mdp\"" );



            $req3 = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO contrat_assurance (id_assurance) VALUES(:id_assurance)');
            $req4 =  $bdd->prepare("INSERT INTO contrat_assurance (id_assure, id_vehicule)  SELECT id_assure, id_vehicule FROM vehicule WHERE immatriculation =\"$imma\"");

            $req3->execute(array(
            'id_assurance' => uniqid()

            ));



        }
```

Actually, I have found other topics about this error, due to my poor skills I can't match the answers with my problem.

Sorry for poor english and French tables names.

Thanks you for reading !

UPDATE : I tried to add the values via the terminal (without PHP), it worked, thus my PHP code is wrong.

UPDATE2 : Here's the PHP code that inserts id_assure into assure table (which is a FK in vehicule table) :

```
try
        {
            $pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
            $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=AAA', 'root', '',   $pdo_options);

            $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO assure(id_assure, nom, adresse, mdp) VALUES(:id_assure, :nom, :adresse, :mdp)');
            $req->execute(array(
            'id_assure' => uniqid(),
            'nom' => $_POST['nom'],
            'adresse' => $_POST['adresse'],
            'mdp' => $_POST['mdp']
            ));


        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, when you are inserting into `vehicule`, you need to specify the foreign key, i.e. you need to insert the value to it, and the value needs to exist in the referencing table. In this form, the only columns into which you are inserting are id_vehicule and immatriculation, which means the id_assure will stay empty, which means the constraint will fail.

Comment: I have already written a form and a php code that insert the id_assure value.

Comment: @Aleks You are inserting `uniqid()`, which is a random unique id. That's wrong, you should be inserting the id of the related entry in `assure` table

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you contact to ukrnow key in query.
I had simular problem, when I have bind **table genders to users**.This bag in **unknown** **key** in to gender in what you have connect via foreign key tables
See ERROR 1452
[image]

And table1 what have different key what have not in table2

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please stop posting the same answer to multiple questions. Your answers need to be substantially tailored to each question. If you feel two questions are identical enough to warrant the exact same answer, flag them as a duplicate.